# Error: .idea not supported - Removing Ionic / Cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to update my packages within my Ionic Project.

When running for example:

```
ionic plugin rm phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
```

I get the error:

```
Error: .idea not supported
```

A Google search reveals nothing.

Comment: `.idea` sounds like a (hidden) directory created by IntelliJ IDEA (and possibly variants like WebStorm and other Jetbrains products). You could try running the command in a different directory (or remove the `.idea` directory after making an backup).

Comment: Odd, only ever used sublime... but removed that from the plugins folder and seems to run fine. Thanks.

Comment: .idea is .gitignore (d)  in the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/ repository, so it must have crept in from somewhere else. @C-Otto - can you put your response as an answer thanks.

Comment: Good idea, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.idea` is a (hidden) directory created by IntelliJ IDEA (and possibly variants like WebStorm and other Jetbrains products). You could try to remove the `.idea` directory from the plugins directory (after making an backup).

Comment: after this step its giving me "Error: gen not supported." . you guys any idea about this?

Comment: Just remove folder called 'gen' created in platforms directory, it worked for me. (I accidentally opened platforms folder inside android studio, which created .idea folder inside platforms folder. So adding / removing plugins for '.idea' platform fails, coz, its not a platform)

Answer (score 3):

I made this command and it worked fine for me :

```
ionic cordova platform rm .idea
```